# Show if x lies in this specified boundary, it must lie in this specific one as well

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $ A \subset X$ of a metric space. Define $bd(A) = \overline{\rm A} \cap (\overline{\rm A^c)} $ to be the boundary of $A.$

Show that If $ x \in bd(\overline{\rm A^c}),$ then $x \in bd(A)$

(I have tried proof by contradiction but am stuck)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$bd(\overline{A^c})=\overline{\overline{A^c}}\cap \overline{\overline{A^c}^c}$

$\overline{\overline{A^c}}=A^c$, $\overline{A^c}^c\subset A$

implies that $bd(A)\subset A^c\cap \overline{A}$

Comment: How is the first part of the second line true?

Comment: The complementary of the complementary of $A$ is $A$.